# Why do not I receive a result when I try to test methods from a web service?

Tags: java, web-services

I started to learn soap web services and I tried to run a simple tutorial from the Internet. I created a simple class with two methods and when I run the project to test the methods, I don't receive any result. Why?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVUak.png)

Comment: Do you have any exceptions?

Comment: No.. Nothing shows up..

Comment: The image shows a SQUARE RED coloured icon which means that it is still running. You sure it completed?

Comment: The square red coloured icon is from apache.. and I don't get any exceptions even  if I put illegal arguments..